Where is the full documentation for mousekeys?
I can't seem to find full documentation for mousekeys.  Many sources explain how to enable it, but nothing provides information on how to use it in any but the most obvious way.
I've discovered that there is at least one non-obvious feature that doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere: pressing /, *, or - on the numpad causes the next press of the 5 key to produce, respectively, a left-, middle-, or right-button click.  Note that I'm using KDE (Wayland) so this feature may be specific to its mousekeys implementation (which I also can't find documentation for).
Is this functionality documented somewhere?  Are there other such features?  I'm specifically looking for a way to send scroll up/down events.

For KDE Plasma, KDE docs maybe more accurate - https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/plasma-desktop/kcontrol/mouse/index.html  (you don't give release details, which makes a difference to as to software stack being used)
